# Opening the console in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is really a two-part question.

My first part is, of course, how to show the console for Javascript, as in have something along the lines of a box on-screen with the console text being shown in it.

The second part is if there is a way to make the console made in my first question, but only appear in a certain spot with a certain width and height.

My final product example would be: I have a picture of a house with a big window, and have a console that you can actually type answers and inputs into, appearing in that window. Is this possible?

edit: the console being able to scale in size with the window would be nice, preferably without an outline.

Comment: Something akin to http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: The console is part of the browser, but you can evaluate code with JavaScript.

Comment: kind of, but not quite. I'm talking about having it display only the output, for example, if I used console.print() it would show up in the box, but the code itself would not be see-able nor editable.

Comment: I don't think you can capture everything that goes to the console, but I believe you can capture anything that is written to the console via 'log', 'debug', 'warn', etc. If you also want to interact with that console, e.g. type in code and see results, that would likely be a bit more coding.

Comment: See [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) on Webmasters.SE

Answer (score 0):

I have needed this in the past and to do it I replace all my `console.log` calls with something like `myconsole.log`. The I implement `myconsole` to output its messages to both the browser's console (if needed) and to a `<pre>` area on my HTML page. If you need user input then I would put a single line `<input type="text">` below the console output panel and implement the appropriate `myconsole` routines to accept user input, copy it into the console panel and call the appropriate handler.

As mentioned, if you need for users to be able to input JS code for execution things quickly get complicated.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This sounds very helpful, but I'm really new to this kinda scene, so I'm not quite sure how to do this, are any tutorials available you recommenced?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is answer you are looking for, but I can share some of my experience with you.

What I often use is something like this:

```
var JS_DEBUG = true; //global var
function Log(str) {
  if(JS_DEBUG) console.log(str);
}
```

And I log all ajax calls and everything that I need with `Log()` function. Once the project is done, all I have to do is to set `JS_DEBUG` to `false` and client has clean code without debug garbage and I save time that I would spend clearing "console.log" calls.

You can also improve `Log()` to do other things when logging into console.

By the way, shortcut for Javascript Console in Google Chrome is **CTRL+SHIFT+J**